# Add a delay, when iterating over an array, for every single element

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, sprite-kit, delay

Trying to use an `SKLabelNode` to display the elements one by one of the array below, on the label. I believe the problem is that it iterates over the array faster than it takes the sequence to run its course, therefore causing a crash because `self.addChild()` is trying to be displayed again for "Set" while "Ready" is still being displayed.

My question is, how do I slow down this iteration so that "Ready" can appear and disappear, before "Set" gets displayed?

```
let readySetGo = ["Ready", "Set", "GO!"]
for i in readySetGo {
    newLevelLabel.text = i
    newLevelLabel.fontSize = 60

    let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2)
    let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([wait, remove])

    newLevelLabel.run(sequence)

    self.addChild(newLevelLabel)
}
```

Comment: is newLevelLabel a UILabel? also adding newLevelLabel thrice to the parent view doesn't seem to make sense

Comment: Is this a countdown for the game? Where in your program is this code - in sceneDidLoad, update() etc?

Comment: this code is in ...override func didMove(to view: SKView), and it s a SKLabelNode...

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it is immediately going to GO is because you do not chain all your actions in the same sequence, so all of your stages are running at the same time:

Try this, I've not the compiler now:

```
let readySetGo = ["Ready", "Set", "GO!"]

newLevelLabel.fontSize = 60

let seq: [SKAction]=[]
let waitTime:TimeIneterval = 2

for i in readySetGo {

    let block = SKAction.run{
        self.newLevelLabel.text = i
    }

    let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: waitTime)

    seq.append(wait)
    seq.append(block)

}

let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: waitTime)
let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
seq.append(wait)
seq.append(remove)
let sequence = SKAction.sequence(seq)

newLevelLabel.run(sequence)

self.addChild(newLevelLabel)
```

Comment: You are incrementing your wait time,  so beween ready and set it is 2 seconds, and between set and go it is 3 seconds.  I think you want to take out `waitTime += 1`

Comment: @Knight0fDragon yes, this is an example to solve the problem, I hope that stinkyProgram know how manage his waiting time

Comment: Thank you so much guys, I've only been programming for 3 months so this is new to me, thank you..

Comment: @stinkyProgram you are welcome. If the solution is correct, please accept it

Comment: @SimonePistecchia `seq` should be a `var` not a `let`, and you misspelled `TimeInterval`.